# RuntimeTypeHandle.Allocate

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

I have coverted project to .Net 4.0 and folowing code doesn't work:

```
typeof(RuntimeTypeHandle).GetMethod("Allocate", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(type.TypeHandle, null)
```

It seems that there is no more  Allocate method in RuntimeTypeHandle class. GetMethod returns null.

What is the analog in .Net 4.0?

Comment: Just a small advice: Normally, there's a reason methods are private/protected/internal...You should NEVER use reflection to call a private method.

Comment: Guys, I know problems when using reflection. The question isn't about this. Let us without such advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new version method signature is:

```
internal static extern object Allocate(RuntimeType type);
```

So I guess you just need to make `BindingFlags.Static` (instead of `Instance`).

Your invocation will be slightly different too.

Comment: Invocation will be very different: RuntimeType is an internal type and it requires a bit of extra effort to invoke methods when you need an instance of a inaccessible type. A hint: have a look at the (also non-public) GetRuntimeType.

Comment: @Abel: My answer refers to the signature on `RuntimeTypeHandle`. While `RuntimeType` is `internal`, calling `GetType` on any instance will return a `RuntimeType`.  :)

Comment: learning something new every day! And I searched so far to get to `GetRuntimeType`, lol! This is much easier, of course.